# ASP.NET MVC Display message when user is logged out

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm creating an app with Identity 2.0 where Admin can ban other users. When they ban them, they're signed out (when they make their next action/request).

Here's my ban action:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Block(ApplicationUser formuser, string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        user.DeleteDate = DateTime.Now;
        user.IsConfirmed = false;
        await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The UpdateSecuritStampAsync does the log out part. Also I think it's good if I insert Startup.Auth.cs UseCookieAuthentication, because I changed a thing there so that the user is logged out(if I miss adding something important, write in the comments, I'll add it)

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account. 
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

I changed the default TimeSpan from 30 minutes to 0 (that might be a mistake but it works).
The main question of this thread is that I want to create something where it would show a message when the user is logged out, how should I go about doing that? (when admin blocks user, the user, after he reloads his page, gets a message that he was blocked for bad use or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use Lock/Unlock the user instead of updating the security stamp. Take a look at [How to lock and unlock account in Asp.Net Identity provider](http://www.byteblocks.com/Post/AspNet-Identity-Lock-and-Unlock-User-Accounts).

```
public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> LockUserAccount(string userId, int? forDays)
{
    var result = await this.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(userId, true);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        if (forDays.HasValue)
        {
            result = await SetLockoutEndDateAsync(userId, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(forDays.Value));
        }
        else
        {
            result = await SetLockoutEndDateAsync(userId, DateTimeOffset.MaxValue);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> UnlockUserAccount(string userId)
{
    var result = await this.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(userId, false);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        await ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(userId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And on your login action or provider you'd use

```
if (userManager.IsLockedOut(userId))
{
    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The account is locked out of the system.");
    return;
}
```

I'm not sure how to notify the user immediately after being lockedout without him/her attempting to login since you don't have the user's ID or username by the time he/she gets redirected to the login page. But if you do, then you can simply use the `IsLockedOut` method to decide whether or not you should display a pop-up saying what it is you want to say to the user.

Comment: but this method locks them out for a couple days, while my method blocks them until someone unblocks them (because you don't really know how long it will take). is there a problem with you doing it like that?

Comment: You can lock someone indefinitely and then unlock them whenever you want, take note that `forDays` is nullable. It's already built-in so I'd prefer you don't attempt re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: okay, well, I will try to change it. But this doesn't really answer my question, as I was asking how do I display to the person locked out that he was locked out. Thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: also this method you offered doesn't logoff. if the user is active, it stays active until he logs off, although he's already locked out in the database

Comment: @HighSepton This will notify the user if he/she attempts to login back to the system. The reason why you can't simply notify about the lockout before the attempt is that you have no idea who the user is at the time of redirection since it is configured in the web.config. Anyway, you're right about the instant logoff part. I forgot about that.